# Is a positive linear functional on $L^p$ necessarily bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I was reading a source that suggested that if $X$ is a measure space (or perhaps just the interval with Lebesgue measure), and if $1 \leq p < \infty$, then any non-negative linear  functional $T$ on $L^p(X)$ is continuous. ($f \geq 0$ a.e. implies $T(f) \geq 0$ as real numbers.) Is this true, or even obviously true?

I read here that positive linear functionals on $C^*$ algebras are continuous, but $L^p$ spaces don't have this structure in general... I also  learned that it is true when $p = \infty$ and $X$ is a countable set with counting measure: [Any positive linear functional $\phi$ on $\ell^\infty$ is a bounded linear operator and has $\|\phi \| = \phi((1,1,...)) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646777/any-positive-linear-functional-phi-on-ell-infty-is-a-bounded-linear-opera) ... however, I don't think the same technique carries over. There is also this question, which is somewhat weaker and more general: [Positive linear functional on an involutive Banach algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/977915/positive-linear-functional-on-an-involutive-banach-algebra)

I also found some discussion  here ( question (2) ): [application of positive linear functionl](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342255/application-of-positive-linear-functionl?rq=1)

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: @Olivier The proof that there are no linear lifts of $L^p$spaces, $p < \infty$, in "Topics in the theory of lifting." Page bottom of page 49, in Theorem 6. https://books.google.com/books/about/Topics_in_the_Theory_of_Lifting.html?id=vTL6CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: A side remark: This holds for positive functionals on $C(X)$. Indeed, if $\|f\|_\infty\le 1$, then $\pm\Re f\le 1$ and $\pm\Im f\le 1$ and thus $|Tf|\le |T(\Re f)| + |T(\Im f)| = T(\pm\Re f) + T(\pm\Im f)\le 2T(1)$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks for pointing that out. That's very similar to the counting measure case... I think the crucial things in both situations is that you have $||f|| - f \geq 0 $, $||-f|| - (-f) \geq 0$.

Comment: @uniquesolution For any dense subspace $C \subset B$, there is an discontinuous functional that is zero on $C$, namely $B \to B / C \to \mathbb{R}$, and thus continuous on $C$. So boundedness can't in general be checked on a dense subspace. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Olivier, If the measure is infinite then it seems that one would need some sort of justification of the fact that positive functionals are bounded.

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't quite get your comment. If $T$ is a positive linear functional on $L^p$, clearly also its restriction to $C(X)$ is positive and hence bounded. But with respect to the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm. I don't see how you can get that it is also bounded w.r.t. the $L^p$-norm.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp - You are right, I deleted my comment.

Comment: Could the statement be false? Consider an $L^p(X)$ with $X$ a finite-measure space. Then $C(X)$ is a subspace of $L^p(X)$. Choose some point $x_0\in X$. Define
a linear functional on $C(X)$ by 
$$\Lambda f=f(x_0)$$
Clearly $\Lambda$ is a positive linear functional. However, it is not bounded in $L^p$, because I can find continuous functions having arbitrarily large values at $x_0$ whose $p$-integral is $1$. By the Hahn-Banach version for positive linear functionals, $\Lambda$ can be extended to the entire space to a positive linear functional, which is not going to be bounded.

Comment: @uniquesolution Can you give a reference for the version of Hahn-Banach you are using?

Comment: @uniquesolution Very nice reasoning! So, the proof in the book is wrong.

Comment: @uniquesolution The hypothesis of the version here (Theorem 2.1) are not met : http://spot.colorado.edu/~baggett/funcchap2.pdf ... since there are $L^p$ functions not dominated by any continuous function, say on the interval.

Comment: Here is my reference, proposition 2.14 of http://bass.math.uconn.edu/fa090614.pdf - I don't want to use Theorem 2.1 that you are referring to. These are of course only sufficient conditions.

Comment: @uniquesolution The spaces $Y$ and $X$ there are of a very specific form (functions on a set). Of course every vector space looks like that, up to isomorphism, but its not clear what the evaluation at $s$ functionals become after we describe $L^p(X)$ as the space of functions on a set. I don't see how to check the hypothesis.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp It's not clear that the Hahn-Banach for positive linear functionals applies here -- at least, I have seen now two versions for which I think that the hypothesis are not met (see discussion above). Do you know a version which applies?

Comment: @AreaMan Ok, indeed, there is a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be any real or complex Banach space of functions or equivalence classes of functions such that with $f\in X$ also $|f|\in X$ and $\||f|\| = \|f\|$ and let $\phi$ be a positive linear functional on $X$. It is easily seen that $|\phi(f)|\le 2\phi(|f|)$ for all $f\in X$.

Suppose that $\phi$ is unbounded. Then there exists a sequence $(f_n)\subset X$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ and $|\phi(f_n)|\ge 2\cdot 4^n$. Put $g_n := |f_n|\ge 0$. Then $\|g_n\|=1$ and $\phi(g_n)\ge 4^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Define the function $h := \sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n}g_n\in X$. Then $h\ge 2^{-n}g_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$ and so $\phi(h)\ge 2^{-n}\phi(g_n)\ge 2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, which is impossible.

Comment: Very nice! So my extension of positive functionals was wrong after all. Just one comment: since $|f|\geq\max\{f,-f\}$, you have $\phi(|f|)\geq|\phi(f)|$, so you don't really need the $2$ factor.

Comment: I consider both real and complex case. ;-)

Comment: Oh, why of course. Thank you.